# Selenium clear a textbox, then re-populate it

Tags: c#, selenium

I've run into a bit of an odd scenario when using the c# selenium wrapper.

I am trying to populate a textbox over and over with multiple different values, and clear it out in between each attempt.  I have discovered that whenever I clear the textbox using either .Clear() or Cntrl A + Del, that the .Text assignment no longer works, but SendKeys still works.

```
        editBox.Text = "test"; // works
        editBox.Text = "test1"; // works
        editBox.SendKeys(Keys.Tab); // works
        editBox.Text = "test2"; // works
        editBox.Text = "third"; // works
        editBox.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a"); // works
        editBox.SendKeys(Keys.Delete); // works
        //editBox.Clear(); // works
        editBox.Text = "fourth"; // DOESN'T WORK
        editBox.SendKeys("fifth"); // works
        editBox.Text = "sixth"; // DOESN'T WORK
```

Is this a bug in Selenium, the wrapper, or in the way I am thinking about how it should work?  I prefer using the .Text assignment generally because it is so much faster for filling long forms.  It would just be nice if I could get it to work after I have deleted the previous value.

EDIT:
Oh bummer, forgot I am using a control that wraps selenium:
.Text wraps
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Browser).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1],arguments[2]);", editBox, "value", value);

The other commands are straight selenium commands, hopefully that helps explain what I am doing.

Comment: Thinking about this from a browser perspective, it does kind of make sense.  After the keyboard has been used on a field, the "value" attribute of that field is going to be ignored.  So I guess the question is, is there anyway to reverse that in a browser.

Comment: If you're replacing the whole contents, then there's no need to clear the box first.

Comment: .Text assignment? Isn't it text "getter"?

Comment: Yes, I had that thought as well.  In this case it will work, but in another part of my code I only fill the value if it is empty, so if this issue were to arise there that would not solve it.  It might be one of those things where I just have to work around it as this is not a bug.

Comment: No, in my case the setter for .Text is what is being activated.  I wrote it that way because I migrated to Selenium from CodedUI, so I wrapped the selenium objects so I wouldn't have to change as much of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just over-looking the obvious.  After the keyboard has been used on a field, the "value" attribute of that field is going to be ignored.

I had to change the javascript I was using to set the textbox value from:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Browser).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1],arguments[2]);", editBox, "value", value);
```

to:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Browser).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1];", _Element, value);
```